# How to add filters into an existing filter function when querying Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, azure, mobile, service, filter

I'm using Azure Mobile Services library for Javascipt in my Angular Web App. According to the documentation here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library.md#how-to-filter-returned-data

There are two ways to filter the returned data. One is passing a JSON object and the other is passing a filter function (for complex filtering). I'm using the filter function since I have to use relational operators for columns like startDate or endDate which require a greater than or less than condition.

I have a function, like the one below, which returns a filter function based on certain filters set on the front end, but to cater different filters, I have to use a lot of if..else conditions to see which of them is set and what filter function to return.

```
function getFilterFunc() {
     if (x != null) {
         if (y != null) {
             return function () { return this.id == xyz && this.x == x && this.y == y; };
         } else {
             return function () { return this.id == xyz && this.x == x; };
         }
     }
     .
     .
     .
      else {
         return function () { return this.id == xyz; };
     }
}
```

It keeps going on like this, I hope you get the idea.

What I am wondering is if there's a better way to generate this filter function. If one can use simply go through all the filters and simply concatenate the conditions onto the single return statement for the filters that are set. Once we've gone through all the filters, we return the statement as a function and use it as a filter function for Azure Mobile Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the body of the filter function is translated into an Open Data Protocol (OData) boolean expression which is passed to a query string parameter. However, you can directly pass an OData query string to the `read` method, and build OData query string as below:

```
var filterStr = "$filter=id eq 'xyz'";
if(x) filterStr += " and x eq '" + x + "'";
if(y) filterStr += " and y eq '" + y + "'";
.
.
.

table.read(encodeURIComponent(filterStr)).then(success, failure);
```

For more information, please see [Execute an OData query operation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/docs/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library.md#execute-an-odata-query-operation).

Comment: Thanks for the response! After doing a bit of research, I chose to switch to the mentioned technique as well. Looking at your response assured me that it was the right approach.